# Length of string results in google apps

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-script

I've a function in gApps spreadsheet that takes a dollar figure multiplies by 100 and then returns the length of the string...

```
function checkWrite(amount) {
amount = amount * 100
amount = amount+'';
var aLength = amount.length;
return(aLength);
```

Return gives the following results:
amount--length
4. ----  3
4.01 --  3
4.02 -- 18
4.03 --  3
4.04 --  3
4.05 --  3
4.06 -- 18

... and so on.  I get many correct answers, 3, and some random wrong ones 18.

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on?  I'm not great at coding, but I'm pretty sure that results should be consistent anyway.

Comment: Load the page in Chrome. Press F12 to load WebInspector. Go to scripts and place a breakpoint in that function and verify the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the numbers are not rounded as you'd expect. Float point values are not exactly represented as you're thinking. To check that you should return the string representation generated as well, e.g. change the last line to `return aLength+' '+amount;`

Anyway, what's the usage of such function? If I have any idea on what you use it for, I could suggest some alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'll try it.  This bit was just to test where the error was occurring.  It creates a function in the spreadsheet that takes a dollar amount and turns it into a written amount for merging into a check run.  So 5.12 turns into Five and 12/100.  Works but for this glitch.

Comment: Exactly as you mentioned... I'm getting some numbers returning.... 15 decimals places.

Comment: Ok, then instead of `amount = amount+'';` use `amount = amount.toFixed(0);`. BTW, since you're new to stackoverflow I'll say, you should check an answer as accepted when you feel you got a good one.